# Solving $y''+xy'+y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, as a homework question, I am trying to solve $y''+xy'+y=0$.

I checked that this is exact and gives 
$$(y'+xy)'=0$$
$$y'+xy = C_1$$
Using integrating factor $e^{\int xdx} = e^{x^2/2}$ :
$$(ye^{x^2/2})' = C_1 e^{x^2/2}$$
At this point, integrating $e^{x^2/2}$ is needed which can't be done (without using the error function).

I did go ahead to solve it and get
$$y=C_1e^{-x^2/2}\int e^{x^2/2}dx + C_2e^{-x^2/2}$$
which doesn't seem to be the solution when subsituted back into the original equation.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Why do you think that its wrong ? Check again the subsitution back into the original equation.

Comment: @JJacquelin Turns out I did something wrong when differentiating. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct and I think it could be book keeping error that prevents you getting back to your ode.

$$
y = C_{1}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\int \mathrm{e}^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}}dx + C_{2}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}= C_{1}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}I +C_{2}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}
$$
if we denote the error integral as $I$ for simplicity we find
$$
y^{'} = -xC_{1}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}I + C_{1}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\left(\mathrm{e}^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\right) - xC_{2}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}
$$
here the derivative of the error function is simple the $\mathrm{e}^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}}$ as you know.
Simplifying yields
$$
y^{'} = -x\left[C_{1}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}I +C_{2}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\right] + C_{1} = -xy + C_{1}
$$
now using that we can take the derivative
$$
y^{''} = -y - xy^{'}
$$
and re-arranging
gives back your original equation
$$
y^{''} + xy^{'}+y = 0
$$