# Solving second order differential equation with mixed partials

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Suppose I wish to solve a differential equation of second order for $y(x)$ with form
$$Ay''(x)+Bxy'(x)+Cy(x)=0$$
We are able to solve using substitution for a guessed exponential form if the $Bxy'(x)$ were a $By'(x)$. How do we deal with the fact that the variable of differentiation is there to solve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solving $y''+xy'+y=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684983/solving-yxyy-0)